# Object's properties won't translate in Flutter with Easy localization

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am trying to translate the properties of my object that looks like that:

```
Category(
  name: "flour".tr(), id: "2", image: AssetImage('assets/wheat-grain.png' ),),
Category(
  name: "alcol".tr(), id: "3", image: AssetImage('assets/liquor.png'),),
Category(
  name: "cream".tr(), id: "4", image: AssetImage('assets/whip-cream.png'),),
```

Everything else work fine, and it is translated as soon as i change language. But in order to translate the categories name, i need to **restart the app**.

Any solutions?

Comment: @lepsch, only you can help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are defining this objects outside of the build method in StatelessWidget. So you can adjust your class with key instead of name(remove tr use in widget). Because easy_localization needs context and when you define your objects you have not any context. If you give key first and after use tr() function in a widget. It will access the context.

```
Category(
 key: "flour", id: "2", image: AssetImage('assets/wheat-grain.png' ),),
```

After then use like this. For example

```
Text(item.key.tr())
```